# New dynamic volume (loop) missed after restart centos

Tags: openstack, centos7, lvm, openstack-cinder, guid-partition-table

I have Centos on my physical drive.
new volume created like commands below:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=cinder-volumes bs=1 count=0 seek=50G
losetup /dev/loop3 cinder-volumes
fdisk /dev/loop3
n
p
1
ENTER
ENTER
t
8e
w
pvcreate /dev/loop3
```

All things goes right and I was happy.
but after reboot, this volume missed.
whats is the problem?
thanks
[image: Befor Reboot]
[image: After Reboot]

Comment: I'm back, and I have added test steps for your help. I just hope this information is helpful for your issue.

Comment: dear @Daein data lost even after your new steps, why new drive missed? can I do some thing to prevent lose of loop3 while reboot?

Answer (score -1):

You can associate the `/dev/loop3` with `cinder-volumes` files as using `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` conf.

**CentOS 6 or less**

```
# vim /etc/rc.d/rc.local

mknod -m 660 /dev/loop3 b 7 3
losetup /dev/loop3 /path/to/cinder-volumes
```

**CentOS 7**

```
# vim /etc/rc.d/rc.local

mknod -m 660 /dev/loop3 b 7 3
losetup /dev/loop3 /path/to/cinder-volumes
```

After modifying, you set the execution flag to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`

```
# chmod u+x /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

And more checks your OS rc-local.service as following,

```
# systemctl list-unit-files rc-local.service
UNIT FILE        STATE
rc-local.service static
```

or

```
UNIT FILE        STATE
rc-local.service disable
```

If the state is disable, you can be enable the rc-local service, but the state is static is not any more conf.

```
# systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

**Updated: Adding restore steps based on hypothesis that refer from questions.**

**★★★In advance, I defined that these steps are just written as the provision of information, I won't be not responsible for data-loss caused by these steps.★★★**

1. Prepare the other server having same specifications as possible as you can.
2. backup the data (here is `cinder-volumes` file) with dd or cp commands
3. check the backup file whether same original data with `md5sum` command.
4. the backup data transfer to the new server for testing.
5. test command; `losetup /dev/loop3 /path/to/cinder-volumes` and `blkid` command for check UUID whether same with the original loop3 device.
6. More tests was always conducted on the new server, not production or important environments.

the loop3 or loopN device is virtual device for using the non-block device as of block device. It is just mapping interfaces. The loop3 device is disappeared but if `cinder-volumes` is clear, no problem.

I hope you it's helpful.

Comment: thank u for your reply.
but loop3 isnt exist while starting os, so losetup cant work in startup

Comment: How about you add this command into rc.local ? `mknod -m 660 /dev/loop3 b 7 3` before `losetup` line. It's create loop3 device.

Comment: are you sure this command recover lost drive and not create new one?
my data didnt lost?

Comment: You need to test above command on non-production and testing env. I just provide you inspiration or information related the issues, I won't be not responsible for data-loss caused by this answer.

Comment: ok, you are not responsible for data-loss :)) , just I want to know your mentioned command create new drive or recover lost drive

Comment: But I checked my testing server before posting , it's CentOS 7.3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158494/discussion-between-vahid-kargar-and-daein).

Comment: I'm so sorry, I can't chat at moment. I have schedule from now.

Comment: please let me to check it
as I understand you are geek in Opnestack, can I have your email address Daein, for ask any question directly? Thank U if you get me your email address

Comment: Thanks @Daein, your solution cause data-loss, please offer a solution which recover loop3 or, prevent losing it after restart.